# Drawing a rectangle bounding box on PDF to get coordinate but inner rectangle filled with white color!! I tried this with online example code only

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, bounding-box, pdf.js

In this code, I have preview the PDF and I can able to draw the bounding box but its filling white color and added screenshot of mine. I can able to get the coordinate using (check it in the console) but the inner text is not visible apart from I need to copy the coordinate once I drew the rectangle in mouse listener so I can paste in anywhere I want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="pdf.js"></script>
    <script src="pdf.worker.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #upload-button {
            width: 150px;
            display: block;
            margin: 20px auto;
        }
        
        #file-to-upload {
            display: none;
        }
        
        #pdf-main-container {
            width: 400px;
            margin: 20px auto;
        }
        
        #pdf-loader {
            display: none;
            text-align: center;
            color: #999999;
            font-size: 13px;
            line-height: 100px;
            height: 100px;
        }
        
        #pdf-contents {
            display: none;
        }
        
        #pdf-meta {
            overflow: hidden;
            margin: 0 0 20px 0;
        }
        
        #pdf-buttons {
            float: left;
        }
        
        #page-count-container {
            float: right;
        }
        
        #pdf-current-page {
            display: inline;
        }
        
        #pdf-total-pages {
            display: inline;
        }
        
        #pdf-canvas {
            /* border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2) transparent; */
            box-sizing: border-box;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            opacity: 1;
            background: none;
        }
        
        #page-loader {
            height: 100px;
            line-height: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            display: none;
            color: #999999;
            font-size: 13px;
        }
        /* #pdf-canvas{
             opacity:0.5;  
             } */
        
        .rectangle {
            border: 1px solid #FF0000;
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="upload-button">Select PDF</button>
    <input type="file" id="file-to-upload" accept="application/pdf" />
    <div id="pdf-main-container">
        <div id="pdf-loader">Loading document ...</div>
        <div id="pdf-contents">
            <div id="pdf-meta">
                <div id="pdf-buttons">
                    <button id="pdf-prev">Previous</button>
                    <button id="pdf-next">Next</button>
                </div>
                <div id="page-count-container">
                    Page
                    <div id="pdf-current-page"></div>
                    of
                    <div id="pdf-total-pages"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <canvas id="pdf-canvas" width="400"></canvas>
            <div id="page-loader">Loading page ...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Rectangle
        "use strict";
        requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
        const canvas = document.getElementById("pdf-canvas");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        // ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;

        const storedRects = [];
        const baseImage = loadImage("");
        var refresh = true;
        const rect = (() => {
            var x1, y1, x2, y2;
            var show = false;

            function fix() {
                rect.x = Math.min(x1, x2);
                rect.y = Math.min(y1, y2);
                rect.w = Math.max(x1, x2) - Math.min(x1, x2);
                rect.h = Math.max(y1, y2) - Math.min(y1, y2);

                jQuery("body").click(function(e) {
                    // ctx.fillRect(50,50,500,500);
                    //   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
                    console.log(rect.x + '=' + rect.y + '=' + rect.w + '=' + rect.h);
                    $('#output').html('current x : ' + rect.x + ', current y : ' + rect.y + ', width : ' + rect.w + ', height : ' + rect.h);

                    if (e.target.id == "pdf-canvas") {
                        ddrag();
                        jQuery(".position_x").val(rect.x);
                        jQuery(".position_y").val(rect.y);
                        jQuery(".position_w").val(rect.w);
                        jQuery(".position_h").val(rect.h);
                    }
                });
            }

            function draw(ctx) {
                // ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)";
                ctx.clearRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
                ctx.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h)
            }
            const rect = {
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                w: 0,
                h: 0,
                draw
            };
            const API = {
                restart(point) {
                        x2 = x1 = point.x;
                        y2 = y1 = point.y;
                        fix();
                        show = true;
                    },
                    update(point) {
                        x2 = point.x;
                        y2 = point.y;
                        fix();
                        show = true;
                    },
                    toRect() {
                        show = false;
                        return Object.assign({}, rect);
                    },
                    draw(ctx) {
                        if (show) {
                            rect.draw(ctx)
                        }
                    },
                    show: false,
            }
            return API;
        })();

        function loadImage(url) {
            const image = new Image();
            image.src = url;
            image.onload = () => refresh = true;
            return image;
        }

        const mouse = {
            button: false,
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            down: false,
            up: false,
            element: null,
            event(e) {

                const m = mouse;
                m.bounds = m.element.getBoundingClientRect();
                m.x = e.pageX - m.bounds.left - scrollX;
                m.y = e.pageY - m.bounds.top - scrollY;
                const prevButton = m.button;
                m.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
                if (!prevButton && m.button) {
                    m.down = true;
                    /*
                    var cv=document.createElement('canvas'); 
                    cv.width=canvas.width;
                    cv.height=canvas.height;
                    */
                }
                if (prevButton && !m.button) {
                    m.up = true
                }
            },
            start(element) {
                mouse.element = element;
                "down,up,move".split(",").forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse" + name, mouse.event));
            }
        }

        mouse.start(canvas);

        function draw() {
            // ctx.fillRect(baseImage, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.width);
            __CANVAS_CTX.strokeRect();

            const storedRects = [];
            // ctx.restore();
            // ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height)
            ctx.drawImage(baseImage, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height)
                // if(__PDF_DOC!=null && __PDF_DOC!=undefined && __PDF_DOC!=null){
                //     showPage(__CURRENT_PAGE);
                // }

            // ctx.drawImage(baseImage, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.width);
            ctx.lineWidth = 1;
            // ctx.strokeStyle = "yellow";
            storedRects.forEach(rect => rect.draw(ctx));
            ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
            rect.draw(ctx);
            // ctx.clearRect(20, 20, 100, 50);
        }

        function mainLoop() {
            if (refresh || mouse.down || mouse.up || mouse.button) {
                refresh = false;
                if (mouse.down) {
                    mouse.down = false;
                    rect.restart(mouse);
                } else if (mouse.button) {
                    rect.update(mouse);
                } else if (mouse.up) {
                    mouse.up = false;
                    rect.update(mouse);
                    //storedRects.push(rect.toRect());
                }
                draw();
            }
            requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop)
        }

        function clearCanvas(canvas) {
            const storedRects = [];
            //alert(jQuery(".position_x").val());
            jQuery('#pdf-contents').removeClass('test');

            // ctx.fillRect(jQuery(".position_x").val(), jQuery(".position_y").val(), jQuery(".position_w").val(),jQuery(".position_h").val());   
            //ctx.clearRect(0,0,jQuery(".position_w").val(),jQuery(".position_h").val());

            //ctx.drawImage(baseImage, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.width);
            //      URL.createObjectURL($("#file-input").get(0).files[0]); /*reload mate*/

            //alert(URL.createObjectURL($("#file-input").get(0).files[0]))
            showPDF(URL.createObjectURL($("#file-input").get(0).files[0]));
            //setTimeout(function(){ showPDF(URL.createObjectURL($("#file-input").get(0).files[0])); }, 3000);

        }

        function ddrag() {
            // ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

            //const storedRects = [];
            jQuery('.test #pdf-canvas').mousedown(function() {
                console.log(jQuery(this).parent().parent().attr('class'));
                if (jQuery(this).parent().parent().attr('class') == "test") {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            jQuery('#pdf-contents').addClass('test');

            //return false; 
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        var __PDF_DOC,
            __CURRENT_PAGE,
            __TOTAL_PAGES,
            __PAGE_RENDERING_IN_PROGRESS = 0,
            __CANVAS = $('#pdf-canvas').get(0),
            __CANVAS_CTX = __CANVAS.getContext('2d');

        function showPDF(pdf_url) {
            $("#pdf-loader").show();

            PDFJS.getDocument({
                url: pdf_url
            }).then(function(pdf_doc) {
                __PDF_DOC = pdf_doc;
                __TOTAL_PAGES = __PDF_DOC.numPages;

                // Hide the pdf loader and show pdf container in HTML
                $("#pdf-loader").hide();
                $("#pdf-contents").show();
                $("#pdf-total-pages").text(__TOTAL_PAGES);

                // Show the first page
                showPage(1);
            }).catch(function(error) {
                // If error re-show the upload button
                $("#pdf-loader").hide();
                $("#upload-button").show();

                alert(error.message);
            });;
        }

        function showPage(page_no) {
            __PAGE_RENDERING_IN_PROGRESS = 1;
            __CURRENT_PAGE = page_no;

            // Disable Prev & Next buttons while page is being loaded
            $("#pdf-next, #pdf-prev").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

            // While page is being rendered hide the canvas and show a loading message
            $("#pdf-canvas").hide();
            $("#page-loader").show();

            // Update current page in HTML
            $("#pdf-current-page").text(page_no);

            // Fetch the page
            __PDF_DOC.getPage(page_no).then(function(page) {
                // As the canvas is of a fixed width we need to set the scale of the viewport accordingly
                var scale_required = __CANVAS.width / page.getViewport(1).width;

                // Get viewport of the page at required scale
                var viewport = page.getViewport(scale_required);

                // Set canvas height
                __CANVAS.height = viewport.height;

                var renderContext = {
                    canvasContext: __CANVAS_CTX,
                    viewport: viewport
                };

                // Render the page contents in the canvas
                page.render(renderContext).then(function() {
                    __PAGE_RENDERING_IN_PROGRESS = 0;

                    // Re-enable Prev & Next buttons
                    $("#pdf-next, #pdf-prev").removeAttr('disabled');

                    // Show the canvas and hide the page loader
                    $("#pdf-canvas").show();
                    $("#page-loader").hide();
                });
            });
        }

        // Upon click this should should trigger click on the #file-to-upload file input element
        // This is better than showing the not-good-looking file input element
        $("#upload-button").on('click', function() {
            $("#file-to-upload").trigger('click');
        });

        // When user chooses a PDF file
        $("#file-to-upload").on('change', function() {
            // Validate whether PDF
            if (['application/pdf'].indexOf($("#file-to-upload").get(0).files[0].type) == -1) {
                alert('Error : Not a PDF');
                return;
            }

            $("#upload-button").hide();

            // Send the object url of the pdf
            showPDF(URL.createObjectURL($("#file-to-upload").get(0).files[0]));
        });

        // Previous page of the PDF
        $("#pdf-prev").on('click', function() {
            if (__CURRENT_PAGE != 1)
                showPage(--__CURRENT_PAGE);
        });

        // Next page of the PDF
        $("#pdf-next").on('click', function() {
            if (__CURRENT_PAGE != __TOTAL_PAGES)
                showPage(++__CURRENT_PAGE);
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: did you manage to solve the issue and get the code working?